# Is it possible to adb connect android via wifi without configuring port on android?

Tags: adb

I can connect via wifi by typing these codes in android terminal -

```
setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
stop adbd
start adbd
```

and connect ip:port on PC adb  .. it is connected
.. Is there any possibility to access without configuring on android !I mean looping port no:. Can it be possible ? kindly suggest me please !

Answer (score 1):

If you have a later version of android (it works on 4.4 for sure), there is a wireless debugging option in developer tools. You can activate that and type this in terminal,

`adb connect <ip address of phone>`

It will default to using port 5555 if you don't give it a port. I think that's what you're after.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I want to use it for older version :(

Answer (score 0):

No. What you're doing there is not just setting a port number away from the default: setting the number at all is what causes the device to start listening. Before you run the steps in the question, the device isn't listening for adb connections on any port at all.

For this reason, there's no "default port" to connect to without setting anything up on the device.

Comment: Yes, Port Defining is vital process .Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you can build the AOSP by yourself. You can add the property to the build.prop:

`service.adb.tcp.port=5555`

Comment: Does this change the value of the default port that is used to connect to my device?

Answer (score 0):

There are Apps on Google Play which make it possible to enable ADB Wifi with a button click. If you have root (as I can see), you won't need a PC and it does the switch in a second. An example App: [ADB Wireless (root) - Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=za.co.henry.hsu.adbwirelessrootbyhenry)
I think that's what you asked for. If you dig deeper you can find apps with the option to set a custom Port. Good luck.